# MongoDB Query para eliminar objetos en un array anidado

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, update, javascript-objeto

Muy buenas, estoy haciendo una migracion de mysql a mongodb y estamos teniendo problemas con arrays anidados de varios niveles. Tengo el siguiente esquema en mongo:

```
 {
ley: {
 id: 1 , 
 bloques: [
   {
    id:1, 
    parrafos: [
     {
      id:1, 
      notas [
       {id:null, texto: null}
      ]
     }
    ], etc...
```

Hay muchos documento de tipo ley cuyas notas de parrafo están a nulo.

Estoy en node.js 10 usando la libreria mongodb version 3.5.4.
Haciendo la operacion de $pull como viene en la doc oficial de mongodb : [Web oficial mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#pull-array-of-documents), no modifica los documentos.

Las estoy intentando eliminar de esta manera:

```
const leyes = db.collection("leyes");

      leyes.updateMany({}, {
        $pull: { 'bloques': { 'parrafos': { 'notas': {  id: { $eq: null }  } } } },
      },
      { 
        multi: true })
```

Según la doc oficial, $pull es el operador que hay que usar para eliminar elementos de un array anidado, ¿me estoy perdiendo algo?

Gracias de antebrazo

Answer (score 3):

Según la documentación, podrías utilizar [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch).

```
leyes.updateMany({}, {
    $pull: { 'bloques': { 'parrafos': { 'notas': {  $elemMatch: { id: { $eq: null } } } } } },
  },
  { 
    multi: true })
```

Comment: Creo que por lo que dice en la doc, el $elemMatch se usa para cuando tienes varias condiciones que quieres que se cumplan antes de hacer el $pull. 

`Then you can specify multiple conditions on the elements of the answers array with $elemMatch:`

Pero aunque lo ponga tampoco funciona